# Codeigniter application for mobile and desktop

Tags: codeigniter, mobile, desktop

I have a codeigniter application for desktop can it be converted to a mobile app when accessed from a mobile using the same code?

Comment: With hindsight I'm not entirely sure whether you mean actually convert it into a full-blown installable app, which isn't possible. It's certainly possible to use the approach I mentioned below to serve different content based on what device is being used. With jQuery Mobile you can get an icon for iOS that lets users add their web app as a bookmark on their home page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, create a responsive design or create one desktop design and a mobile design based on the user agent.

If your design is easy to adapt for both worlds (desktop and mobile) with a little tweaking and a responsive design should be enough to do the trick. But before you choose this way remember that you have plenty of mobile devices with many screen resolutions.

I advise you to read this slideshow about the mobile web:
http://www.slideshare.net/bryanrieger/rethinking-the-mobile-web-by-yiibu

And just for information the types of mobile devices we have on the market.
http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

To help you out with responsive design you can use some of the frameworks available on the internet:

Twitter bootstrap : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Foundation 3: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Skeleton: http://www.getskeleton.com/

YAML 4: http://www.yaml.de/

You can see more frameworks here http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html

In case your desktop layout doesn't fit as a proper mobile layout you can rely on the user agent, although he is not 100% accurate, and build two different layouts.
On the desktop side you can use some of the responsive frameworks mentioned before, for the mobile side you can use:

jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/

iUI: http://www.iui-js.org/

UI ON TARGET: http://www.rikulo.org/

The best is a mix of the two worlds, a responsive design for small and large screens for users  on a desktop and a proper design for mobile users.

Answer (score 2):

the different between two is in the template or view part of application .
basically you have to identify visitor device and if it is a mobile show him the mobile view that you have prepared  .

you can create great responsive mobile template using jquery mobile .

Comment: +1 for jQuery Mobile. That's also my recommendation for building a mobile interface quickly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done exactly this in the past.

What I did is I used the user agent class to detect whether the user agent was a desktop or mobile client, and used that to set a flag in the sessions. Based on that, I served different views depending on the value of that flag. This approach has the advantage that the URLs remain the same regardless of which interface you're using.

I would recommend adding a way to manually override this, though, since detecting the user agent is never going to be 100% accurate.